# Hiding "0" in title of any part of {report} documentclass

Tags: report

I have a report which is structured part just look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[compact,explicit]{titlesec}  
\begin{document}  
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}  

\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  

\end{document}
```

All the  `\section{Pasal}` generate title section Pasal 0.1, Pasal 0.2, etc. Please help, I don't have any idea to erase the 0.

Comment: Why are you using `report`, that has chapters, and not `article`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[compact,explicit]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\begin{document}  
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}  

\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  
\section{Pasal}  

\end{document}
```